# How to reset the tableview cells accessorytype to none on a click of a button?

Tags: uitableview, nsindexpath

I am trying to code a reset button, so that when I click on that button all the tableview cells' accessory type get set to `none`.

I have a clear concept of how to do it, but I am pretty new to iPhone development so I just need help with what methods to call.

The steps I think I need to take: I am iterating through all the rows using a for loop - so I am counting the number of cells (successfully done). My problem is, I have no clue how to check for each of those rows/cells if the accessory type is CheckMark and set it to `none`.

Alternatively, I can set all of my cells to `AccessoryNone`, but I am already doing some calculations inside the:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

So I am not sure how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No need to check what the `accessoryType` is first, just assign `UITableViewCellAccessoryNone` to all of them.  This should work for what you are trying to do:

```
// replace clickedResetButton with your action handler method for that button
- (IBAction)clickedResetButton:(id)sender {
    for (int section = 0, sectionCount = self.tableView.numberOfSections; section < sectionCount; ++section) {
        for (int row = 0, rowCount = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section]; row < rowCount; ++row) {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section]];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            cell.accessoryView = nill;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3.1

```
func resetAccessoryType(){
    for section in 0..<self.tableView.numberOfSections{
        for row in 0..<self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section){
            let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: row, section: section))
            cell?.accessoryType = .none
        }
    }
}
```